# Amazon SNS で production にて通知実行した結果、Endpoint が disabled になる

Tags: swift, ios, aws

Amazon SNS にて、[push norification platform] を 'Apple Production' で作成した Application にて、iOS から作成した Endpoint に対して、
[publish to Endpoint] でテキストを送信したところ、以下のエラーが発生してしまいます。

> Endpoint is disabled (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: EndpointDisabled; Request ID: ～)

iOS アプリケーションから作成された Endpoint の Enabled が false になっている点に問題があると認識しており、
UIから強制的に true にしても、false になってしまいます。

[push norification platform] を 'Apple Development' で作成した場合は Enabled が true となり、
[publish to Endpoint] でテキストを送信したら正常に通知を受信できます。

当エラーの真因はどこにあると推測できますでしょうか。
ヒントでも良いので、どなたかご教授ください。

SNSへの Endpoint への create は以下の手順で行っております。

**Endpointを作成する処理**
・起動時に Cognito Identity から Credentials を取得
・通知送信時に、DeviceToken取得 → SNSに登録
・通知送信時に、メッセージを SNS に対して push

**無効な Endpoint に対して push した際の Error 内容**

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>NotFound</Code>
    <Message>Endpoint does not exist</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId></RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もういいやって思い本番環境に移行したら正常に通知処理を行うことができました。
'Apple Production' の確認は本番でないと通知確認はできない、ということで認識しました。